# passing a observer and passing a lambda to a skipUntil method

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

```
RxJava 2
```

I have the following 2 examples of how a skipUntil is used:

This one passes a lambda function to the skipUntil:

```
   sourceSubject
            .skipUntil<Int> {
                triggerSubject.subscribe(it)
            }
            .subscribeBy { println(it) }
```

And this one passes the observer:

```
sourceSubject
        .skipUntil(triggerSubject)
        .subscribeBy { println(it) }
```

However, I am confused with the method signature as it only seems to take a Observer and I couldn't see the lambda. Just wondering why I can pass a observer and pass a lambda to this function

Here is the method that just seems to show passing in an Observer:

```
public final <U> Observable<T> skipUntil(ObservableSource<U> other) {
        ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(other, "other is null");
        return RxJavaPlugins.onAssembly(new ObservableSkipUntil<T, U>(this, other));
    }
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

This feature is knows as the [SAM Conversions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions). it basically means

> if an object implements a SAM interface (***one with a
>   Single Abstract Method***), you can pass a lambda instead of creating and passing an object of the given interface.

In your case `skipUntil` expects a `parameter` of type [ObservableSource](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/ObservableSource.html) and since `ObservableSource` is `SAM interface`, you can pass a `lambda` instead of a full fledged `object` of type `ObservableSource`.

So even though there is no `skipUntil` `function` which expects a `lambda`, you can pass one because of [SAM Conversions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions).